# IBM speech to text- How can I convert MP3 audio file into an array of bytes

Tags: android, ibm-watson, speech-to-text, android-sdk-2.3

IBM speech to text- How can I convert MP3 audio file into an array of bytes to send to a server in IBM Watson to convert the audio into text using speech to text API

Comment: well you could use thius library https://github.com/Kaljurand/speechutils

Comment: i will try this sir thank you

Comment: sir i have a question is this supported with speaker labels like identifying speaker who is speaking?

Comment: Well thats not you asked for in the question . However you have some tools available to work out someting for that you need to check :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech/getstarted/getstartedjavaandroid      Also if yoou need content recognition . As in you need to find specific singer in audio file you can get all the help in this library :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech/getstarted/getstartedjavaandroid

Answer (score 0):

You can convert mp3 to bytearray like this;

```
fun convert(context: Context): ByteArray {

        val outputFile = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).absolutePath + "/sample.mp3"

        var soundBytes = ByteArray(0)
        try {
            val inputStream = context.contentResolver.openInputStream(Uri.fromFile(File(outputFile)))
            soundBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        return soundBytes
}
```

Java

```
public byte[] convert(Context context) {

    String outputFile =
            Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath() + "/sample.mp3";

    byte[] soundBytes = new byte[0];
    try {
        InputStream inputStream =
                context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.fromFile(new File(outputFile)));

        soundBytes = new byte[inputStream.available()];
        soundBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return soundBytes;
}
```

Comment: sir? whati method is this ? fun convert(context: Context): ByteArray {?

Comment: sir what is fun convert method?

Comment: this is Kotlin language, are you using Java?

Comment: android studio sir yes sir

Comment: sir? can you merged the converting bytes in ibm watson speech to text api in above code please sir help me

Comment: sir help me how can i put the method sir